# radtooltipmanager not working with ajaxcontroltoolkit accordion

Tags: ajax, telerik, toolkit

i have an ajaxcontroltoolkit accordion that contains datalist ,

and i 've a tooltipmanager on element inside datalist ,

tooltip doesn't work,
TargetControls is added inside datalist_ItemDatabound event ..

any help please ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [radtooltipmanager add targetControl using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900329/radtooltipmanager-add-targetcontrol-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

If the ACT accordion is the problem (and not AJAX, as suggested in your other thread) try removing the AjaxControlToolkit assembly from your project and use only Telerik controls. They have a PanelBar that should do the trick: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx.