# radtooltipmanager add targetControl using ajax

Tags: ajax, telerik

I have a radtooltipmanager that have their target control inside datalist.  This datalist is bound on the server side using ajax.  I set the target control from itemdatabound event of datalist, but tooltip doesn't work.

Any help please.

Comment: Please include your code.  Also try to specify the ClientID instead of the ID, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AJAX to initially bind the list (i.e., it does not happen on the initial load, but during a subsequent partial postback), make sure that you include the RadToolTipManager in the partial update, because otherwise its new targets will not travel to the client.